# UIAlertController to go to new ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have generated a UIAlert and I want to link this to open a new viewController. I have added new files for each of the different viewcontrollers i have and have linked the class.

the code i have is ..

```
@IBAction func CorrectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct Answer", message: "Congratulations", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let vc = ThirdViewController()

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

basically when the user clicks on the correct answer the alert will pop up and then when the user clicks "OK" i want a new viewcontroller to pop up with the next part of the app. all that is currently happening is when i click the "ok" in the alert message the screen is going black?

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instatise the viewController you want to go to in the completion handler of the okButton.

This is an example that i use.   Its a class function that i can call from anywhere, i have hard coded the view controller i want to go to which is part of a navigation controller, just change "LogInNavCont" to the storyboard id of your viewcontrolller and UINavigationController to UIViewController if its a stand alone viewController.

if you don't want to use it as a class function, just replace className.present to self.present

```
class func createAlertAndGoToLogin(errorTitle: String, errorMessage: String, className: UIViewController) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: errorTitle, message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        // go back to the login view controller
        // go back through the navigation controller

            let vc = className.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInNavCont") as! UINavigationController
            className.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)


    }))
    className.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```